# ASP.NET MVC - Can I use the commom ASP.NET user's role configuration with MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to use the commom ASP.NET role's configuration on an ASP.NET MVC application?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Web Forms can both use the role configuration that ships with ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! The role provider just provides a set of common contracts to manage users and groups ("roles") they are in. Everything works the same in MVC as in traditional WebForms - once the user is identified via login or however you handle that (authentication provider and membership provider), any role-specific code you write will work in either.